# Partial iteration of a generator using for ... of

Tags: javascript, generator

Here is a `test` function, which gets a first item from a sequence using `for ... of` loop. And after that it gets a second item:

```js
function test(iterable) {
  const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  for (const item of iterator) {
    console.log('First: ' + item);
    break;
  }
  for (const item of iterator) {
    console.log('Second: ' + item);
    break;
  }
}

function test2(iterable) {
  const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  const item = iterator.next();
  if (!item.done) {
    console.log('First: ' + item.value);
  }
  for (const item of iterator) {
    console.log('Second: ' + item);
    break;
  }
}

const obj = {
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    yield* [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  }
}

console.log('test:');
test([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
test(obj);

console.log('\ntest2:');
test2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
test2(obj);
```

It works fine for an array. But it doesn't work for a generator. In the later case it doesn't get the second item.

However `test2` function works fine in both cases.

Is it an expected behaviour or a bug?

Comment: I think it's expected bahavior - iteration can be breaked in other way eg. iterator can use parameters and inner conditions to generate as much oputput as you need. Also there is other way to achieve break - calling iterator.next() as long as you need. And last method iterate through an array generated from an generator like `[...myGenerator()]`

Comment: I thought that it's absolutly normal to break iteration in `for ... of` and to continue it later. At least it works fine for arrays. Agreed that `test2()` looks better than `test()`. And It's a preffered way to stop iteration. I just can't explain the behaviour of `test()` function and trying to understand it.

Comment: If you do `test([...obj]);` result is the same as in `test([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);`, it is indeed interesting.

Comment: Yes, `[...obj]` is just a plain array created using the generator. So, it's equivalent to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` in the scenario.

Comment: You may want to run `node --print-bytecode yourSnippet.js` on test and test2 and diff two outputs to inspect the case further I don't know the answer.